# I can't install any package with tlmgr: " Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022)."

Tags: pdftex, texlive

I have a MacOS and when I'm trying to install any Latex package in the console, say I type

```
sudo tlmgr install texlive-lang-russian
```

I got the following error message from MacOS:

```
tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022).
Cross release updates are only supported with
update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I tried to type `update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update` as suggested but this does not work. Could you please explain what I should do to update the package?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, you typed only the `.exe` extension  in windows or only the `.sh` extension in Linux, but not both "as is" ... right?

Comment: @Fran yes, the answer is "-bash: update-tlmgr-latest.sh: command not found"

Comment: you would need ./update-tlmgr-latest.sh as . isn't usually in the path but the recommended way is to install 2022 from scratch not attempt an update from 2021 to 2022. I don't have a mac, but it seems you are using a raw *ix style texlive install, I think most mac users use mactex which is texlive re-packaged in a more macos style

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your comment. This is what I got: -bash: ./update-tlmgr-latest.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: @Oleg sure you need to get that file from the site you show, but why not use mactex? see step 8: `Download the latest update-tlmgr-latest.sh and run it like this: `

Comment: https://tug.org/mactex/